# This request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, angular, request, parameter-passing, payload

I saw other similiar post with answers but since it's not helping me i'm posting this.

I'm using Java/Angular 11, i'm making Post Request sending data in FormData but it keeps giving me

```
Request part 'file' is not present
```

My Server

```
@PostMapping(value = /add, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))
    public ApiResponseEntity add(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                 @RequestParam("foo") Foo foo) throws IOException {
```

My Client(Angular)

```
formData = new FormData()
this.formData.append("file", ev.target.files[0]));
this.formData.append("foo",JSON.stringify(FooDTO));

this.httpClient
                .post<any>(this.baseURL + apiURL + "/add", entity, this.httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);
```

My Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundarysDMcWqKZNsayiMSX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="abc.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundarysDMcWqKZNsayiMSX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

{
...
}
------WebKitFormBoundarysDMcWqKZNsayiMSX--

Where did i go wrong? Thanks for viewing and answering!

NOTE: HttpOption has Content-type: multipart/form-data, i also tried to use @RequestPart but the result still the same

UPDATE: Sorry i forgot to show my POST method parameters
here's the full version

```
public add(formData: any, apiURL: string): Promise<any> { 
        console.log(formData)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpClient
                .post<any>(this.baseURL + apiURL + "/add", formData, this.httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);
        });
    }
```

What i did was after i sort out my formData i pass it into add method above to call API

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing formData in your http post, modify the below line of code from

```
this.httpClient
                .post<any>(this.baseURL + apiURL + "/add", entity, this.httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);
```

as below

```
this.httpClient.post<any>(this.baseURL + apiURL + "/add", formData, this.httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply , i just updated my code so you have a better understanding!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue today. At the end I decided to gave up Angular HttpClient and used the native XMLHttpRequest instead.

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open("POST", this.baseURL + apiURL + "/add", true)
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    console.log(request.responseText);
  }
};
request.send(formData);
```

While this is not a direct solution, it solves the problem if your goal is to simply implement an API call to upload files.
I would still appreciate it if anyone can point out what's missing from HttpClient.